# In Mac OS, How to list all functions used by executable from dynamic library?

Tags: macos, dyld

I tried to override network socket related function in Mail app. But I'm not sure if Mail app uses Core foundation socket or POSIX socket.

I use otool -l to find dynamic loaded library in LC_LOAD_DYLIB section. However, I want to know what exact functions it calls.

Answer (score 6):

`nm` will show you the imported symbols.
Use `nm -ufm /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail` to get symbols and the libraries/framework they came from.

Comment: The `-f` flag has a different meaning with llvm-nm (the current version of `nm` in macOS). So now the example should be `nm -um /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail`

Answer (score 0):

Install binutils package in MacPorts, then use gobjdump?